# jtable only populates one row with value from the linkedlist

Tags: java, jtable

so i have this class that holds the name, address and city of an employee. afterwards the class is been stored in a linkedlist & when the user enters the name , address and city in a textfield, the values are being inserted into the linkedlist, and then populated on a jtable. so far, i have been able to get the user details and added it to the likedlist, but when i click on the add button, it only adds one row to the table, if i insert some other values in the textfield and click on the addbutton again, it just removes the previously added row and adds the new one still displaying just one row, i want the jtable to display all values. here is my code please.

```
public class EmployeeDetails extends javax.swing.JFrame {
String [] str = {"NAME", "ADDRESS", "CITY", "ZICODE"};
LinkedList<EmployeeDetails> linkedlist;
String name;
String address;
String city;
String zipcode;


public EmployeeDetails(String name, String address, String city, String zipcode) {
   this.name = name;
   this.address = address;
   this.city = city;
   this.zipcode = zipcode;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setAddres(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setZip(String zipcode) {
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
}

public String getZip() {
    return zipcode;
}

public String toString() {
    return name + " " + address + " " + city + " " + zipcode;
}

public EmployeeDetails() {
    initComponents();
}

//this is the method that does the adding
public void add() {
    name = nametxt.getText().trim();
    address = addresstxt.getText().trim();
    city = citytxt.getText().trim();
    zipcode = zipcodetxt.getText().trim();

    linkedlist = new LinkedList<>();
    linkedlist.add(new EmployeeDetails(name, address, city, zipcode));
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(str, linkedlist.size());

    for(EmployeeDetails details : linkedlist) {
        System.out.println(details);
        model.addRow(new Object[]{details.getName()details.getAddress(), details.getCity(), details.getZip()});
    }

    employeeTable.setModel(model);
}
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand, what exactly you are trying to do. Why are you creating Employee object within POJO class?

Comment: Take a look at you `add` method.  It creates a new `LinkedList` adds a single `EmployeeDetails` (which extends from `JFrame`!! This is not going to end well), creates a new `TableModel` and adds (the single) `EmployeeDetails` to it and then applies it to the `employeeTable` ... why are you surprised?

Comment: I think you should go have a look at [How to add a JPanel repeatedly using an 'ADD' button? How to call a JPanel in the ActionListener()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143526/how-to-add-a-jpanel-repeatedly-using-an-add-button-how-to-call-a-jpanel-in-th/52143899#52143899) which is, as far as I can tell, is the same assignment, for some better ideas over how you should be managing your data and ui

Comment: thank you @MadProgrammer i'd read it up. i actually did create another class to handle the employee details but what i was trying to do wasn't really working and i was looking for a way to make my code less bulky, so i did what i did without knowledge that it was a bad idea, thanks anyway you're amazing!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your `add` method.  It creates a new `LinkedList` adds a single `EmployeeDetails` (which extends from `JFrame`!! This is not going to end well), creates a new `TableModel` and adds (the single) `EmployeeDetails` to it and then applies it to the `employeeTable` ... why are you surprised?

There is no reason why `EmployeeDetails` should extend from a UI based component, it provides zero benefit to you.  The `EmployeeDetails` class is also not responsible for managing the UI in any shape or form.

One of the key aspects of OO development is the separation of responsibilities.  The `EmployeeDetails` should manage the employee details, nothing else...

```
public class EmployeeDetails {

    String name;
    String address;
    String city;
    String zipcode;

    public EmployeeDetails(String name, String address, String city, String zipcode) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setAddres(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setZip(String zipcode) {
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zipcode;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + address + " " + city + " " + zipcode;
    }

}
```

While `DefaultTableModel` is a powerful and flexible model, it's also ... somewhat basic.  For me, I prefer something which can manage the objects it's displaying and make better decisions about how they should be displayed.  This is even more critical when it comes to the models mutable state (should allowing add, removing or even editing of the individual rows?)

In your case, you want to be able to at least add new `EmployeeDetails` objects...

```
public static class EmployeeTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    
    protected static String [] COLUMN_NAMES = {"NAME", "ADDRESS", "CITY", "ZICODE"};
    
    private List<EmployeeDetails> rows = new ArrayList<>(25);

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return rows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        EmployeeDetails ed = rows.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0: return ed.getName();
            case 1: return ed.getAddress();
            case 2: return ed.getCity();
            case 3: return ed.getZip();
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public void add(EmployeeDetails ed) {
        rows.add(ed);
        int row = rows.size() - 1;
        fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
    }
    
    public void remove(EmployeeDetails ed) {
        int row = rows.indexOf(ed);
        if (row < 0) {
            return;
        }
    }
    
    public void remove(int row) {
        if (row < 0 || row > rows.size()) {
            return;
        }
        rows.remove(row);
        fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
    }
}
```

The model doesn't do anything else other then manage the state of the model.  I more complex solution might have an additional model/controller to manage how new objects are created and existing objects are updated or deleted, but I'll leave that up to you to add in.

And finally, we can stitch it all together...

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private EmployeeTableModel model = new EmployeeTableModel();
    
    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(model)));
        
        JButton add = new JButton("Add");
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int row = model.getRowCount();
                EmployeeDetails ed = new EmployeeDetails("Employee " + row, "@ " + row, "Metro" + row, Integer.toString(row));
                model.add(ed);
            }
        });
        add(add, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
    
}
```

A simple panel with a button and a table, now you can mash the add button and watch your employee list grow...hope you have good funding ;)

Make sure you take the time to have a read through [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) which has lots of important and relevant information as well as runnable examples you can play with

## Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private EmployeeTableModel model = new EmployeeTableModel();

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(model)));

            JButton add = new JButton("Add");
            add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int row = model.getRowCount();
                    EmployeeDetails ed = new EmployeeDetails("Employee " + row, "@ " + row, "Metro" + row, Integer.toString(row));
                    model.add(ed);
                }
            });
            add(add, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

    }

    public static class EmployeeTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        protected static String [] COLUMN_NAMES = {"NAME", "ADDRESS", "CITY", "ZICODE"};

        private List<EmployeeDetails> rows = new ArrayList<>(25);

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return rows.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            EmployeeDetails ed = rows.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0: return ed.getName();
                case 1: return ed.getAddress();
                case 2: return ed.getCity();
                case 3: return ed.getZip();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void add(EmployeeDetails ed) {
            rows.add(ed);
            int row = rows.size() - 1;
            fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
        }

        public void remove(EmployeeDetails ed) {
            int row = rows.indexOf(ed);
            if (row < 0) {
                return;
            }
        }

        public void remove(int row) {
            if (row < 0 || row > rows.size()) {
                return;
            }
            rows.remove(row);
            fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
        }
    }

    public class EmployeeDetails {

        String name;
        String address;
        String city;
        String zipcode;

        public EmployeeDetails(String name, String address, String city, String zipcode) {
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
            this.city = city;
            this.zipcode = zipcode;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setAddres(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setZip(String zipcode) {
            this.zipcode = zipcode;
        }

        public String getZip() {
            return zipcode;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name + " " + address + " " + city + " " + zipcode;
        }

    }

}
```